# selinux and starting init process from httpd

Tags: rhel, selinux

OS: RHEL6 and CentOS6

When starting a service such as ntpd (`/etc/init.d/ntpd start`), the process will have the selinux context:

```
system_u:system_r:ntpd_t:s0
```

If I have a cgi that is setuid of root that will allow stop/start of services through a web interface, when starting through this cgi (executing same `/etc/init.d/ntpd start`) the process has the selinux context:

```
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
```

My cgi file selinux context:

```
system_u:system_r:unconfined_exec_t:s0
```

How can I make it so when services started through the httpd/cgi suid process executing the `/etc/init.d script` to start a service, has the correct type on the process? (`ntpd_t` in this example)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there are transitions between domains in SELinux, so it means which process and what context type runs/starts what process and from what file (what SELinux context). So the sysV or systemd starts service by default from systemd_t or something so, but your web server try to start the service from httpd_t. Google how to change domain in SELinux.